# Trying to create a specific data-target for bootstrap modal through ruby iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, each, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modal on my rails project. On this page I have to iterate through my slides and for each slide I want to create a modal. I came up with this solution:

```
<% @slides.each do |slide| %>
    <div class="row slidecard text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 ">
          <h2><%= slide.name.upcase %></h2>
          <p><em><%= slide.description %></em></p>
          <a href="#" data-target=<%=slide.id%> data-toggle="modal">
          <%= image_tag slide.picture.url(:medium) %>
          </a>
          <div class="modal fade" id= <%=slide.id%>>
            <div class="modal-dialog mymodal">
              <div class="modal-content text-center">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <%= image_tag slide.picture.url(:original) %>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
          </div
        </div>
```

I give to the link containing the image the data-target attr and gives it the value that has the slide.id so I can give a specific id and data target that links image and modal. But the problem is that for the modal to work I need to add "#"in front of slide.id to have something that looks like data-target="#39"
I tried a couple of things such has :

```
data-target= "#"<%=slide.id%>
```

and other stuff but nothing gives me the result I want and make the modal work !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <a href="#" data-target= <%= "#" + slide.id.to_s %> data-toggle="modal">licence</a>
```

try to this

Comment: I tried already, it doesnt work, if you inspect the html in the page you get
data-target= "#{slide.id}"

Comment: I m sorry I realised I did a copy paste error... the content of the <a> tag must not be licence but the image_tag, so that is correct as it is. The problem is that for the bootstrap modal to work, I need to have in my html a tag something that looks like:

 <a href="#" data-target="#39" data-toggle="modal"> where 39 is <%= slide.id%> the probleme is that I need to have the "#" before the slide.id number for the modal to work.

Comment: by triying your last proposal I  get :
"no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String"